# Variable Scope: How VBA Decides When to Override Variables

Tags: excel, variables, scope, vba

I have the following VBA code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub problem1()
    Dim speedmph As Double, speedkph As Double, speedfts As Double

    speedmph = Val(InputBox("Enter a speed (mph)"))
    Call convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)
    MsgBox "The speed is " & speedkph & " km/hr and " & speedfts & "ft/s."

End Sub

Sub convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)
    speedkph = speedmph * 1.609
    speedfts = speedmph * 1.467
End Sub
```

I've noticed that when I called the convert procedure as it is shown above, it worked.
But if I tried to insert a value for speedkph (e.g.  0),  the `convert` 
procedure does not override that  and MsgBox prints out 0 for speedkph.

Why doesn't  `convert` override the `0` even though it forces
the variable to change in its function definition?

Comment: What kind of "placeholder" are you talking about?

Comment: Do you mean something similar to `string.Format("{0}{1}", foo, bar)` in .NET?

Comment: @Comintern I don't know what you mean. By placeholder, I meant instead of running `Call convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)` I use `Call convert(speedmph, 0, speedfts)`.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  In that context, `0` is a number, not a variable. If you need to pass the value back by reference, `speedkph` ***is*** the "placeholder".

Comment: Ok I took out the word placeholder. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `speedkph` you `Dim`med in `problem1` is not the same `speedkph` you declared in `convert`. They are completely unrelated and VB has no way to know that the value `convert` put into its `speedkph` argument must be saved into the `speedkph` variable. To understand that better, give your `Dim`med variables completely different names but keep `Sub convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding scope, the parameters for a `Function` or `Sub` only have scope within the `Function` or `Sub` that they are declared in.  The same thing holds true for variables declared with the keyword `Dim` (or `ReDim` for arrays).  For *undeclared* variables, the scope is the next highest scope if a matching identifier exists (module level private variables, then global variables). If no identifier with a greater scope exists, it is implicitly declared as a `Variant` in *local* scope.  So, in this line...

> ```
> Sub convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)
> ```

...the parameters `speedmph`, `speedkph`, and `speedfts` are all local to `Sub convert` (and are implicitly `Variant` because there aren't `As` statements), and in this line...

> ```
> Dim speedmph As Double, speedkph As Double, speedfts As Double
> ```

...the parameters `speedmph`, `speedkph`, and `speedfts` are all local to `Sub problem1()`.

---

That out of the way, let's address ***why*** your `MsgBox` shows anything at all.  The default method of passing parameters is `ByRef`, so if you were to actually specify all of the implicit parts of your `Sub` declaration, it would look like this:

```
Public Sub convert(ByRef speedmph As Variant, ByRef speedkph As Variant, _
                   ByRef speedfts As Variant)
```

When you call it like this...

> ```
> Call convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)
> ```

...you pass it ***references*** to the local variables `speedmph`, `speedkph`, `speedfts` you declared in `Sub problem1()`.  The `Sub convert` assigns values to those references, but each procedure only holds it's own ***copy*** of the reference in local scope.  The identifiers are completely irrelevant at this point.  In fact, this works exactly the same as your sample code (only the identifiers have been changed):

```
Sub problem1()
    Dim speedmph As Double, speedkph As Double, speedfts As Double

    speedmph = Val(InputBox("Enter a speed (mph)"))
    Call convert(speedmph, speedkph, speedfts)
    MsgBox "The speed is " & speedkph & " km/hr and " & speedfts & "ft/s."

End Sub

Sub convert(foo, bar, baz)
    bar = foo * 1.609
    baz = foo * 1.467
End Sub
```

---

Now to answer your specific question, the reason you can't use a "placeholder" value of `0` is that `0` isn't a variable - it's a literal. When it's passed to `Sub convert`, the only place the reference exists is as a variable on the call stack - `Sub problem1()` doesn't hold a reference to it, so there's no way for `Sub problem1()` to tell *what* `Sub convert` does with it.  The stack variable is destroyed when `Sub convert` returns and the call stack unwinds. Basically, passing a literal to a `ByRef` parameter is functionally equivalent to passing it `ByVal`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.